# PhpStorm : How to comment shortcut on notebook AZERTY?

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

I don't know how to use the shortcut (Ctrl + Slash) on my notebook. I don't have any numberpad.

I tried ctrl, ctrl shift, ctrl alt,... Nothing works.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Just go to `Setting/Preferences | Keymap`, find the right action .. and assign another (more suitable for you) shortcut. Right now this question is about computers (your notebook) rather than programming/IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to go under setting and put your own

Under `Keymap > Main menu > Edit > Code` change the `Comment with Line Comment`

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's the only way to do it :)